# Can't connect to local MySQL server through socket '/var/lib/mysql/mysql.sock' (2)

Tags: linux, mysql, redhat

This is NOT a duplicate of [Can’t connect to local MySQL server through socket ‘/var/lib/mysql/mysql.sock’](https://serverfault.com/questions/65050/cant-connect-to-local-mysql-server-through-socket-var-lib-mysql-mysql-sock)

The issue there was of insufficient disk space. No such problem here.

I have a mysql setup on a Redhat Centos 5.5 system, which was working fine until I restarted it.

The webapplication spits out:

```
 Can't connect to local MySQL server through socket '/var/lib/mysql/mysql.sock' (2)
```

when trying to connect to it.

I'm not able to run:

```
 root@server [~]# /usr/bin/mysql_secure_installation
 ...
 Enter current password for root (enter for none):
 ERROR 2002 (HY000): Can't connect to local MySQL server through socket '/var/lib/mysql/mysql.sock' (2)
```

Irrespective of what I enter (root password, earlier mysql password, or blank), it still says the same thing.

Also:

```
root@server [~]# cat /var/log/mysqld.log
101021 18:37:34  mysqld ended
```

---

Edit1: After doing  service mysqld restart

```
101022 00:43:46  mysqld started
101022  0:43:46  InnoDB: Started; log sequence number 0 2820714
101022  0:43:46 [Note] /usr/libexec/mysqld: ready for connections.
Version: '5.0.77'  socket: '/var/lib/mysql/mysql.sock'  port: 3306  Source distribution
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try restarting it to see if there are any error messages.

```
service mysqld restart
```

Comment: It started up my application, but I'm not sure if it ended my problems... The log output in Edit1

Comment: Sounds like it's not set to run at startup then. `chkconfig mysqld on`

Comment: Precisely that! I did that, did a restart to check and voila!